# Python - Check presence all column name dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from csv with 3 columns ('id', 'Local' , Sales').
Every Week, i have to run my script with a new csv.

I want to check after read csv the presence of this 3 columns with the good name.
If i have just 2 columns 'id' and 'Local', i want a warning because missing 'Sales'
If i have 'ID', 'Local', 'Sales', i want a warning message because i need 'id' and not 'ID'.

I tried to create a list with all columns and compare Dataframe.columns == list, but it's not working.

Someone can help me.
Thank you

Comment: _but it's not working._ Can you be more specific? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that you have written so far? That would help us debug the specific warnings you are getting

Answer (score -1):

*This answer assumes that your CSV will only contain at most 3 column names with the column names you provided in any order. If the CSVs also contain additional column names unrelated to the column names you provided, this solution will need some modifications to achieve your desired outcome.*

You could create a variable representing the list of required columns and then use set comparison to verify that the new CSV contains exactly those columns, in any order.

```
req_columns = ['id', 'Local', 'Sales']

set(Dataframe.columns) == set(req_columns)
```

If you don't care about the case of the column names, you could ignore the case by converting all of the column names to lower/uppercase:

```
set([x.lower() for x in Dataframe.columns]) == set([x.lower() for x in req_columns])
```